# SignIn Component doesn't redirect to Dashboard component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using Firebase Authentification service. I want my user to be redirected to the dashboard when he login with his user creadentials. the problem is that the route for the dashboard is not working. I searched the firebase documentation and couldn't find something helpful. Can anyone help me with this problem.

**SignInForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom/dist";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const SignInForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const auth = getAuth();

  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(userCredential);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const routeChange = () => {
    let path = `/resetpass`;
    navigate(path);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={signIn}>
      <div className="sign min-h-screen bg-base-200">
        <div className="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row-reverse">
          <div className="text-center lg:text-left">
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">Sign In</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="card flex-shrink-0 w-full max-w-sm shadow-2xl bg-base-100">
            <div className="card-body">
              <div className="form-control">
                <label className="label">
                  <span className="label-text">Email</span>
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  className="input input-bordered"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-control">
                <label className="label">
                  <span className="label-text">Password</span>
                </label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  className="input input-bordered"
                />
              </div>
              <label className="label">
                <a href="#" onClick={routeChange}>
                  Forgot Password?
                </a>
              </label>
              {/*<div>{active === true && <PasswordReset />}</div> */}
              <div className="form-control mt-6">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                  Sign In
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignInForm;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [authenticated, setauthenticated] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
    if (loggedInUser) {
      setauthenticated(loggedInUser);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!authenticated) {
    // Redirect
    return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome to your Dashboard</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Fragment } from "react";

import Home from "./Home/pages/Home";
import Navbar from "./shared/components/navigation/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import React from "@heroicons/react";
import Contact from "./Contact/pages/Contact";
import Admin from "./Admin/pages/Admin";
import SignInForm from "./Contact/components/SignInForm";
import PasswordReset from "./Contact/components/PasswordReset";
import Dashboard from "./Contact/components/Dashboard";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="root-div">
      <Router>
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/signin" exact element={<SignInForm />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are actually redirecting to `/dashboard` in the code you provided and [I don't believe Firebase handles redirections automatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth).

You can try adding a manual redirect when `signInWithEmailAndPassword` succeeds:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(userCredential);
        navigate('/dashboard');
      })
```